# How can I stop parent events from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, function

If I have...

```
<div id="parent" onmouseover="doSomething()">
    <div id="child" onmouseover="doSomethingElse()">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that doSomething() is not executed when I'm hovering over the child? I only want doSomethingElse() to execute when I'm hovering over the child, and I only want doSomething() to execute when I'm hoving over the parent.

Whenever I hover over the child, both functions execute. Any ideas?

Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomethingElse(e) {
// your function body

e.stopPropagation() 

}
```

Comment: Isn't that a jQuery function?

Comment: no it is pure javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.stopPropagation

Comment: @Marwan: nitpick - it's not JS, it's DOM level 2, ie it's specified by W3C, not ECMA

Comment: re-nitpick.  It's a JS /binding/ to a DOM level 2 specification.  Marwan never said it was specified by ECMA.

Comment: re-re-nitpick: in common usage, JavaScript either refers to ECMAScript or an actual browser-specific implementation thereof; you chose to include the browser API in this definition, I didn't; if you use the term correctly (ie for Mozilla's ES implementation), the DOM API is independant of JS: Rhino (an implementation of JS1.7) doesn't support the DOM, as it's not part of the language spec

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute value to

```
onmouseover="doSomethingElse(event)"
```

and change `doSomethingElse()` to

```
function doSomethingElse(e) {
    e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: the cancelBubble is not a standard property. It is better to use the stopPropagation method

Comment: @Marwan: if you want to ignore IE users, go ahead, but check the browsers of your target audience beforehand

Comment: So long as IE ignores the standards it deserves like treatment.  Eye for an eye, and all that jazz.  ;-)

Comment: Henceforth, The Wicked Flea shall be known as a champion of the biblical approach to web-design and follower of The Book of Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but there should be a few ways to do it.

Please check event bubbling : it's different in IE and Firefox but still:
www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html